# Why I am getting wrong output 2686924 instead of 281?

Tags: c++, sum, output, cout

I am new to C++ and learning about it.

Here is a code I have written for Problem No 4 but it's not giving the output.

I am having two problems:

1. ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<stdio.h>

   int main(){
   int a,b,c,d,e,f;
   int a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2;

   int answer;

   a=1;
   b=2;
   c=3;
   d=4;
   e=5;
   f=6;

   a2=11;
   b2=22;
   c2=33;
   d2=44;
   e2=55;
   f2=66;

   7+8+14;
   a+a2;
   b+b2;
   c+c2;
   d+d2;
   e+e2;
   f+f2;

   answer=answer;
   cout<<"Answer is"<<answer;
   }
   ```

It showed me error 'cout' is not declared in the scope but i am using c++ only.

2. But when i changed this code:

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<stdio.h>

   int main(){
   int a,b,c,d,e,f;
   int a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2;

   int answer;

   a=1;
   b=2;
   c=3;
   d=4;
   e=5;
   f=6;

   a2=11;
   b2=22;
   c2=33;
   d2=44;
   e2=55;
   f2=66;

   7+8+14;
   a+a2;
   b+b2;
   c+c2;
   d+d2;
   e+e2;
   f+f2;

   answer=answer;
   printf("Answer is:");
   printf("%d",answer);
   }
   ```

This give output 2686924. The output is wrong it should print 281. I have checked every line but no error shows please tell why output is not showing.

Comment: What do you imagine `answer=answer;` does?

Comment: `7+8+14;` also doesn't do anything, nor do any of the lines below it. I'm guessing you intended to write `a += a2`?

Comment: as well as you will have to use  std::cout

Comment: answer prints the sum of all numbers

Comment: Got it but just use either using namespace std; or std::cout      'cout' is not declared in the scope but i am using c++ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many statements in your code that literally DO NOTHING,

```
7+8+14;
a+a2;
b+b2;
c+c2;
d+d2;
e+e2;
f+f2;
```

and

```
answer=answer;
```

You see, answer is uninitialized. You never set it's value in the code, so you need something like

```
// Initialize `answer' here
answer = 7 + 8 + 14;
answer = answer + a + a2;
answer = answer + b + b2;
answer = answer + c + c2;
answer = answer + d + d2;
answer = answer + e + e2;
answer = answer + f + f2;
```

Also,doyouunderstandthislineoftext? You can't without spaces right! Well the same goes for the code.

Comment: doyouunderstandthislineoftext hahahah  humor??

Comment: @HariomSingh No, it's just that I hate when there is no spaces around operators. I am comparing it's "*unreadability*" to the equivalent in english.

Comment: thank you for answer but it is still showing error cout is not declared in the scope.

Comment: @anthony You need `std::` the namespace, because `cout` is certainly not declared outside the `std` namespace. DO NOT DO `using namespace std;` just do `std::cout << whatever << std::endl;`.

Comment: thanx it worked. but can you plaese tell what is difference between std::cout and cout?

Comment: @anthony Read the chapter in your book about namespaces.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi -- and don't do `std::endl` but use `'\n'`. There's no need here for the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.